# OCMock setup for OSX with CocoaPods

Tags: ocmock

Trying to setup OCMock for a OSX project. 
Problem is I am not getting any framework to add to my test target, only
the static library. I doubt it should be like that.

In my Podfile I have the following: `pod 'OCMock', '~> 2.2'`

Comment: Cocoapods adds your dependencies as static lib(s), not as frameworks.

Comment: According to the website it says
For OS X development add OCMock.framework to your test target.
Import <OCMock/OCMock.h> at the top of your unit test.
http://ocmock.org/

Comment: That applies in case you are setting the dependency manually but you are using Cocoapods.

Comment: Ok in that case, the includes are of the wrong type in the files, i.e. <OCMock/xxx.h> should be changed to "xxx.h". Seemed strange having to change it manually.

Comment: You can still use <OCMock/OCMock.h> I think.

Comment: Actually I get a compile-time error and XCode suggests to change from <> to "". That is one of the reasons I am posting here :).

Comment: In my case I also use cocoapods(maybe a different version) and have <>, not "". I think it depends on where cocoapods sets the pods header search paths, if it's in "Header Search Paths"(I have them there) or in "User Header Search Paths".

Comment: You hinted me in the right direction with "Search Path". See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by selecting the project in XCode and select "Yes" under "Always Search User Paths".