# Unable to recognize header file of OCMock

Tags: ios, ocmock

I am a newbie to IOS and trying to setup OCMock framework to my existing project. i followed the instructions given in the website http://ocmock.org/ios/.  After adding as requested , I did clean the project and did a test rebuild and nothing worked. -- while I try to import OCMock/OCMock.h , it says file not found.

I did the following three in the Build Settings:

1. Add $SRCROOT/Libraries ( recursive ) to Header search path
2. To Other Linker flag - added "-ObjC" , also tried "-all_load" to check if that works.
3. Also tried to update Library search paths, after going through few other posts.

In Build Phases
1 ) the new library libOCMock.a got auto linked

And nothing is showing up in the Copy Bundle Resources sub category in Build Phases.

The file structure , At root of my project folder , added Libraries subfolder , and add the library and the header files under it.

Please guide me with any troubleshooting tips. Also for some reason i am not seeing any console logs , while i do the clean and rebuild.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284442/ocmock-setup-for-osx-with-cocoapods Try using cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with another framework. Try adding the header search path to the "User Header Search Paths" under Build Settings.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32620919/2870783
Removing all entries but the inherited one from the Framework Search Path.